# Bootstrap Newbie, I want the function of table 1 differ on table 2

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, html-table

I have a unique error and I am not able to fix it. The thing is, I have a timesheet table that let me add multiple data inside. I want it only to be on Table #1, but as soon as I click the + sign in my table, the same data keeps on showing in my Table #2. I already checked different sites about this. But I cannot find the proper answer. Please help me.
This is the code for my Table #1

```
$(function () {
  var TABLE = $(".table");

  //start time
  var start_time;
  var end_time;
  var break_time_start;
  var break_time_end;
  var end_time;
  var add_time;
  var hours_array = [];
  var minutes_array = [];

  $('.table').on('change', '.appt1', function () {
    start_time = $(this).val();
  });


  //break time start
  $('.table').on('change', '.appt2', function () {
    break_time_start = $(this).val();
  });

  //break time finish
  $('.table').on('change', '.appt3', function () {
    break_time_end = $(this).val();
  });

  $('.table').on('change', '.appt4', function () {
    end_time = $(this).val();

    let end_time_with_date = moment(end_time, 'HH:mm:ss');
    let start_time_with_date = moment(start_time, 'HH:mm:ss');

    let break_time_start_with_date = moment(break_time_start, 'HH:mm:ss');
    let break_time_end_with_date = moment(break_time_end, 'HH:mm:ss');

    //computeTime(start_time,break_time_start,break_time_end,end_time)  

    let compute_hours_break_time = break_time_end_with_date.diff(break_time_start_with_date, 'hours');
    let compute_minutes_break_time = parseInt(moment.utc(moment(break_time_end_with_date, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(break_time_start_with_date, "HH:mm:ss"))).format("mm"))

    let compute_hours = end_time_with_date.diff(start_time_with_date, 'hours') - compute_hours_break_time;
    let compute_minutes = parseInt(moment.utc(moment(end_time_with_date, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(start_time_with_date, "HH:mm:ss"))).format("mm")) - compute_minutes_break_time

    $(this).closest('tbody tr').find('td:eq(8)').text(compute_hours)
    $(this).closest('tbody tr').find('td:eq(9)').text(compute_minutes)

  });

  function compute(element) {

    let hours_sum = 0;
    let minutes_sum = 0;
    $(".total_hours_hidden").each(function () {
      console.warn(parseInt($(this).text()))
      hours_sum += parseInt($(this).text());

    })

    $(".total_minutes_hidden").each(function () {

      minutes_sum += parseInt($(this).text());

    })

    $(".total_hours_worked").text(hours_sum);

    $(".total_minutes_worked").text(minutes_sum);


  }

  $(".compute_button").click(function () {

    compute();
    
  })

  //end calculation code

  $(".table-add").click(function () {
    console.log('adding');

    var clone = TABLE
      .find("tr.hide")
      .clone(true)
      .removeClass("hide table-line");
    TABLE.append(clone);
  });

  $(".table-remove").click(function () {
    $(this)
      .parents("tr")
      .detach();

    compute();

  });

})
```

and this is on my Table Html file.

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div id="table" class="table-editable">
    <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>START TIME</th>
          <th>SITE NAME</th>
          <th>TASK</th>
          <th>OTHERS</th>
          <th>BREAK TIME START</th>
          <th>BREAK TIME FINISH</th>
          <th>END TIME</th>
          <th style="display:none">HOURS HIDDEN</th>
          <th style="display:none">Minutes HIDDEN</th>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
      <tbody>
        <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
        <tr class="hide">
          <td><input type="date" size="1" class="date"></td>
          <td><input type="time" class="appt1" name="appt" required=""></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
          <td><input type="text" size="10"></td>
          <td><input type="time" class="appt2" id="appt2" name="appt" required=""></td>
          <td><input type="time" class="appt3" id="appt3" name="appt" required=""></td>
          <td><input type="time" class="appt4" id="appt4" name="appt" required=""></td>
          <td class="total_hours_hidden" style="display:none">0</td>
          <td class="total_minutes_hidden" style="display:none"> 0</td>
          <td class="table-remove"> x</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button class="compute_button">
    Calculate
  </button>

  <table style="width: 100%">
    <colgroup>
      <col span="1" style="width: 15%;">
      <col span="1" style="width: 70%;">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Total Hours: </th>
        <th>
          <div class="total_hours_worked" style="display:inline"></div>:
          <div class="total_minutes_worked" style="display:inline"></div>

        </th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and this is for table #2.

```
<div class="card" id="oncallTable" style="display:none">
  <h3 class="card-header text-center font-weight-bold text-uppercase py-4">
    ON CALL TIME SHEET
  </h3>
  <!-- Start of scrollable box -->
<div class="card-body">
  <div id="" class="table-editable">
    <!-- <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> -->
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>DATE</th>
          <th>START TIME</th>
          <th>SITE NAME</th>
          <th>TASK</th>
          <th>OTHERS</th>
          <th>BREAK TIME START</th>
          <th>BREAK TIME FINISH</th>
          <th>END TIME</th>
          <th style="display:none">HOURS HIDDEN</th>
          <th style="display:none">Minutes HIDDEN</th>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

This is because both your tables table#1 and table#2 have the class name 'table'. So your code:

```
var TABLE = $(".table");
```

is referencing to both the tables because of  which your code:

```
TABLE.append(clone);
```

will append the data to be appended to both the tables.
Instead, you could provide your table#1 a unique id as:

```
<table id="table-1" class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
```

and in your TABLE variable you can select table#1 as:

```
var TABLE = $("#table-1");
```

That would pretty much fix the issue.

Comment: Hello, i tried following your code, it seems that other code like this seems not to work in your answer. Please help, thanks.
They now can not be found on my table
$('.table').on('change', '.appt1', function () {
    start_time = $(this).val();
  });


  //break time start
  $('.table').on('change', '.appt2', function () {
    break_time_start = $(this).val();
  });

  //break time finish
  $('.table').on('change', '.appt3', function () {
    break_time_end = $(this).val();
  });

Comment: So on clicking plus icon, you want to append the hidden code with class 'hide' to table#1 only but it's currently being appended to both the tables right?

Comment: Yes, It always append on all the tables. but the problem is with this one.  $('.table').on('change', '.appt1', function () { start_time = $(this).val(); }); //break time start $('.table').on('change', '.appt2', function () { break_time_start = $(this).val(); }); //break time finish $('.table').on('change', '.appt3', function () { break_time_end = $(this).val(); });

Comment: i am talking about the $('.table')

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the lines you mentioned above?

Comment: it also add rows in my 2nd table

Comment: In your code: $(".table-add").click(function () {
    console.log('adding');

    var clone = TABLE
      .find("tr.hide")
      .clone(true)
      .removeClass("hide table-line");
    TABLE.append(clone);
  });
In this function, you have : TABLE.append(clone); , which appends the html to the element with class name 'table', and in your case you have two tables with the class name 'table', hence this is causing the rows to be added to both the tables.

Comment: To avoid this, give a unique id to your first table like I have mentioned in my answer as: <table id="table-1" class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
and replace the line : TABLE.append(clone); with this: 
 $('#table-1').append(clone); . And this should fix your problem.